# How to properly parseJSON?

Tags: json, http, go, parsing, web

I need to parse JSON, the response comes in this format

```
[{"buyer":"EcUx5JGHhJ9Y4qR6HR8TDHqi5QC3MNNqHf1dbGdHyaxW","count":1,"foxy":false,"id":276870,"mint":"SH1f6At4pScGi42Xfp6tvf9eKirfMd5bi2oPmxdpUAF","price":2700000000.0,"seller":"wxo1Rj8JAy52FhhqTSiPTNbGZH87RhyMrgKJZiyYcay","time":"Sun, 17 Apr 2022 16:23:43 GMT","txid":"5rVfRfb4pLQf4XT9Mo4uxpntpJEDuG1NknkGZZjLYrPJ6gAJLUevD2inCeumBJoAiTLbGCET1m1E4M93qprSyYEA"},{"buyer":"82LTEczYDDnUUkcHUKo9BnHh4m3NbGeAUUcRCHHQYG8u","count":1,"foxy":false,"id":276867,"mint":"SH1f6At4pScGi42Xfp6tvf9eKirfMd5bi2oPmxdpUAF","price":2500000000.0,"seller":"HSoxmbJt9k7dSJe5P7qebu1jRUS6NH8wPZpmx2WafeDy","time":"Sun, 17 Apr 2022 16:23:22 GMT","txid":"2ynUJRM2nBYjaJRCVbT4FY21k8xvWJk8tV4JFjjSVpegsoQXAWRp7rn3WBZJ92h1GHfg5i54fh1G5Wu9NcL5F1d"},{"buyer":"8gs1PiG8r1RhfQWD6HziG9AJSfFayJA4GvDeXz6bREqF","count":1,"foxy":false,"id":276866,"mint":"SH1f6At4pScGi42Xfp6tvf9eKirfMd5bi2oPmxdpUAF","price":2600000000.0,"seller":"En326iJ7gg2KsgH8SsMES9H42M5YTGN8XZzbQa7bsHmX","time":"Sun, 17 Apr 2022 16:23:15 GMT","txid":"3kzkVvjtRPTsrgNDNHdhZiMPbKo3H52Ta47MqSGcDNDaEp4EEFqfXWXuq8ny7hV4hZkW6QaXWm7B8ns2uBpzmz8T"},
```

My code:

```
type Data struct {
Buyer string `json:"buyer"`
Count int    `json:"count"`
Price int    `json:"price"`
Time  string `json:"time"`
Txid  string `json:"txid"`


    resp, err := http.Get(scheme + host + getSalesByAdress)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Can't get data from link", err)
}
var Data []Data
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &Data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Can't unmarsahl JSON", err)
}
fmt.Println(Data[0].Price)
```

Error: .\main.go:22:13: undefined: Data

Comment: It looks a bit like `Data` is defined in a file other than `main.go` and you are trying to execute the code using `go run main.go`? Am I close? If not, then can you perhaps include a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

Some issues that are visible are that data is redeclared twice and that the type is not closed. You could try this and see if it works for you.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    type Data struct {
Buyer string `json:"buyer"`
Count int    `json:"count"`
Price int    `json:"price"`
Time  string `json:"time"`
Txid  string `json:"txid"`

}
    resp, err := http.Get(scheme + host + getSalesByAdress)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Can't get data from link", err)
}
var data []Data
body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Can't unmarsahl JSON", err)
}
fmt.Println(data[0].Price)
}
```